# Does libcurl support RTSPS?

Tags: c, ssl, libcurl

I'm trying to talk to an RTSP server via TLS using libcurl.

When trying to send the RTSPS request to the server the curl request fails:

> libcurl error: 'Protocol "rtsps" not supported or disabled in libcurl'

libcurl is built with RTSP support (enable-rtsp) and plain RTSP requests *do* work.

Does libcurl support RTSPS or not?

If not why not? What's the technical difference between RTSPS and HTTPS that makes this a problem?

The embedded platform I'm on is currently using version 7.72.0 of the library, but I could update if that's the problem).

I have not found any information on Google or curl.se directly about RTSPS support.

The RTSP [sample](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/rtsp.html) only shows RTSP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, libcurl does not support RTSP over TLS as of 7.77.0.

The reason is quite simply: nobody has bothered to add support for it.

Adding support for it should be fairly straight-forward and could follow a similar pattern used by many other protocols libcurl already supports.